# GFS Grib Wind Values Decode And Convert (U & V)

Tags: php, math, equation, weather, grib

Im doing a Grib2 decoder in PHP, and started with a half written library that I found. Everything is working fine except the values I get from the data are incorrect after converting Int Values to real values. I think I am converting everything right, and even when I test with cloud data it looks correct when I check it in Panoply. I think its with this formula that is all over the internet. Below im using 10 m above ground GFS from https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov

```
Y*10^D = R+(X1+X2)*2^E
```

Im not sure I'm plugging in the values correctly but again it works with cloud cover percentages.

So.... The "Data Representation Values" I get from Grib  Section 5

```
      'Reference value (R)' => 886.25067138671875,
      'Binary Scale Factor (E)' => 0,
      'Decimal Scale Factor (D)' => 2,
      'Number of bits used for each packed value' => 11,

      'exp' => pow(2, $E), //(Equals 1) (The Library used these as the 2^E)
      'base' => pow(10, $D), //(Equals 100) (And the 10^D)

      'template' => 0,
```

As you can see below the numbers definitely have a connection to the Reference Value. The Number closest to 886(R) is 892 and its actual value should be 0.05 as shown below (EX.) The numbers Higher are than 892 are positive and the ones lower than 892 are negative. But when I user the formula (886 + 892 * 1) / 100 it give me 17.78, not 0.05. I seem to be missing something pretty obvious, am I misunderstanding the formula/equation where Y is the value I want...

```
X1 = 0 (documentation says)
X2 = 892 (documentation says is scaled value, the value in the Grib from bits?) 
2^0 = 1
10^2 = 100
R = 886.25067138671875

Y * 10^D = R + (X1 + X2) * 2^E
Y * 100 = R + (X1 + X2) * 1
886  + (0 + 892) * 1 ) / 100  
(886 + 892 * 1) / 100
= 17.78
```

Int Values of wind from Grib (After converting from Bits)

```
      0 => 695,
      1 => 639,
      2 => 631,
      3 => 0,
      4 => 436,
      5 => 513,
      6 => 690,
      7 => 570,
      8 => 625,
      9 => 805,
      10 => 892,<-----------(EX.)
      11 => 1044,
      12 => 952,
      13 => 1081,
      14 => 1414,
      15 => 997,
      16 => 1106,
      17 => 974,
      18 => 1135,
      19 => 1069,
      20 => 912,
```

Actual decoded wind values shown in Panoply (Well known Grib App)

```
-1.9125067
-2.4725068
-2.5525067
-8.862507
-4.5025067
-3.7325068
-1.9625068
-3.1625068
-2.6125066
-0.81250674
0.057493284 <-----------(EX.)
1.5774933
0.6574933
1.9474933
5.2774935
1.1074933
2.1974933
0.87749326
2.4874933
1.8274933
0.2574933
```

Answer (score 0):

`y = 0.01 * (x - 886.25067138671875)` seems to work for all points

so `0.01 * (892 - 886.25067138671875) = 0.0574`

Comment: @the-way is it working for you now?